# Prove that $\{(i, j, k)$ in $\mathbb{N}\}$ is countable

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have the following definition...
$$T=\{(i,j,k)\mid i, j, k \in\mathbb{N}\}$$

How do I prove whether it is countable? My understanding is that I need to prove that every subset of $(i,j,k)$ maps to some number $n$.

For example...

$1$ maps to $(1,1,1)$

$2$ maps to $(1,1,2)$

etc...

But I'm not sure how to show my proof. Can I possibly use Cantor's argument? How would that work here?

Comment: There is something wrong with this task. $(i,j,k)$ is no subset of $\mathbb{N}$, it is not even a set.

Comment: @Cornman ok maybe it is not a subset. I assumed it was because it was in the brackets.

Comment: When you want to make brackets you have to write \{ ... \} and not just { ... }. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regard this mapping
\begin{align}
\phi: \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
T & \to & \mathbb{N} \\
(i,j,k) & \mapsto & 2^i 3^j 5^k
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}
It is certainly injective. Therefore $|T| \leq |\mathbb{N}|$.

Comment: can you just explain why it is so obviously injective? Im confused, lets say $i$ $j$ and $k$ are $1$. Then all three map to the same value? In this case they map to $30$?

Comment: Each number has an unique factorization, then this function is injective.

Comment: $(i,j,k)$ is one element! So "Then all three map to the same value" doesn't make any sense.

Comment: it is called godel coding.  $f(i,j,k) =2^i 3^j 5^k$.  It uses the fundamental theorem of arithmetic to encode an ordered tuple from $N^n$ into a unique natural number.  For example $f(2,1,3)=(2)(2)(3)(5)(5)(5)= 1500$.  To find what unique tuple corresponds to 1500, find the prime factors $1500=(2)(2)(3)(5)(5)(5)$, then the number of 2s goes to the i position, the number of 3s goes to the j position, the number of 5s goes to the k position.  In otherwords $f^{-1}(1500)=(2,1,3)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$T = \Bbb N \times \Bbb N \times \Bbb N$. Now if you could show that if $A, B$ are countable then so is $A \times B$...

Comment: I'm still a little confused, what do A and B represent?

Comment: @Bolboa just generic sets with the property of being countable.

Comment: so I have to first prove that a generic set is countable?

Comment: @Bolboa That will prove to be rather difficult since it's just false. The cartesian product of two countable sets is itself a countable set. That's what you ought to show.

Answer (score 1):

You only need show that exists a injective function from $T \to \mathbb{N}$.

I believe that is more interesting prove that finite cartesian product of countable set is countable. Your exercise will be a particular result.

Now for prove that cartesian product you can use induction in number of set (n). For n=2, you can only think about $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$(why?). To construct injective function $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ you can think about prime factorization.